# python - delete item from list of tuple by index

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

I want to delete elements from list of tuple with given index values.

**Input**: `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]`

**Task to be done**:
delete item at given index: 2,3

**Desired output**:
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (9, 10)]

I have tried following code for it:

```
list(numpy.delete(input, [3,2]))
```

But I got following output:
`[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Kindly suggest me possible ways to solve this case.

Answer (score 3):

list.pop() will remove selected elements. they have to be done in reverse order so as not to modify the position of the later ones.

```
list.pop(3)
list.pop(2)
```

Comment: Close, you need to pop(3) first since pop(2) renumbers all elements after the deleted element.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `del`:

```
del mylist[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

### `numpy`: specify the axis for multidimensional arrays

What you did with numpy was close but you used the wrong axis. If you specify `axis=0` you get the result you wanted.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]  
>>> l = np.array(l)
>>> l
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])
>>> np.delete(l, [2,3], axis=0)
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

### Vanilla Python

For operations that mutate the list step by step, it's important to go by descending order of the indices so e.g. `[3, 2]` instead of `[2, 3]`:

**With `pop()`**

```
>>> l = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]  
>>> l.pop(3)
(7, 8)
>>> l.pop(2)
(5, 6)
>>> l
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (9, 10)]
```

**With `del`**

```
>>> l = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]  
>>> for i in [3, 2]:
...     del l[i]
... 
>>> l
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (9, 10)]
```

**With `remove()`**

```
>>> l = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]  
>>> remove_list = [l[2], l[3]]
>>> remove_list
[(5, 6), (7, 8)]
>>> for r in remove_list:
...     l.remove(r)
... 
>>> l
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (9, 10)]
```